# Deploying a pre-compiled Vapor service

Tags: swift, nginx, vapor

Our team has a Vapor service that we deploy on a Mac through an NGINX reverse proxy. It works as expected.

The problem is, every time we deploy a new instance via `sudo swift run`, Vapor compiles the code from scratch, checks for dependencies, etc.

Is there a way to pre-compile the service and simply have it deployed out of the box?

Comment: You can take compiled executable binary and just launch it on another machine, but another machine should have absolutely same environment: same OS, same versions of installed libs which swift relate to.